# Build errors with new kotlin 1.1 , kapt cant parse databinding params

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-interop

I updated my project from android studio 2.2 to android studio 2.3 and incremented the project from kotlin 1.06 to kotlin 1.1

This is the error I get

```
    :app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:transformClassesAndDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugKotlin
w: The '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-module' is specified
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Processor path was modified by kapt. Previous value = /home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.0/ef03cfed144ff47eed2cab1f7be4381bc18a6237/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/2.3.0/compilerCommon-2.3.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.1/constraint-layout-solver-1.0.1.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.2.0/support-annotations-25.2.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.0/96a07041a11a09cf578892932d7511e1e11e3b6c/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.3.0/baseLibrary-2.3.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.airbnb.android/epoxy-annotations/1.7.5/509abda14719aa31f55123c9a757bdadc8f45818/epoxy-annotations-1.7.5.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-annotations-processor/3.0.0/61c2ac9e7a068736558e69d585cfa777b35058b2/realm-annotations-processor-3.0.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/annotations/24.5.0/annotations-24.5.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/3.7.0/9e9eeaf9948ee4d6c3ab354e8dc14368f16994a4/glide-3.7.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.6/de0c509ae6c9db5b5b6004a9d102c92708346f7c/rxjava-1.2.6.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.11.0/840897fcd7223a8143f1d9b6f69714e7be34fd50/okio-1.11.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/adapter-rxjava/2.2.0/d80514b6f44f0c4c6234e2d67fea783a25e77275/adapter-rxjava-2.2.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/2.3.0/compiler-2.3.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-annotations/3.0.0/32a01bbb8cb421b6d53d7a102412142b0391c8c7/realm-annotations-3.0.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.2.0/41e67dba73c3347e4503761642c39d0e06ca1f2/retrofit-2.2.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.6.0/69edde9fc4b01c9fd51d25b83428837478c27254/okhttp-3.6.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/478fd1ace0e77af57c87f42a281aed180d5ce276/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/d7d6ec093cb49766f796118979b331d6f5c2b4c4/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-annotations/3.0.0/32a01bbb8cb421b6d53d7a102412142b0391c8c7/realm-annotations-3.0.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/17205aea1b3195cf38fb66c2e060ee4beed141f8/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/adapter-rxjava/2.2.0/d80514b6f44f0c4c6234e2d67fea783a25e77275/adapter-rxjava-2.2.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.2.0/41e67dba73c3347e4503761642c39d0e06ca1f2/retrofit-2.2.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.6.0/69edde9fc4b01c9fd51d25b83428837478c27254/okhttp-3.6.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.11.0/840897fcd7223a8143f1d9b6f69714e7be34fd50/okio-1.11.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.6/de0c509ae6c9db5b5b6004a9d102c92708346f7c/rxjava-1.2.6.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/3.7.0/9e9eeaf9948ee4d6c3ab354e8dc14368f16994a4/glide-3.7.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/6249fbc26c3c324164d6bccd213e772dbffabab8/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/00346f3603afd369923753ca5b3574b3cbd68913/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/44456db0af44370448077b85155ec1b111460aaf/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/ab1b9ebddb2122246c96bfd338f92a2af4329445/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.airbnb.android/epoxy-annotations/1.7.5/509abda14719aa31f55123c9a757bdadc8f45818/epoxy-annotations-1.7.5.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/fb128d6e98efde38d1b59985fb85f2eee1b186eb/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/c9550d2fd003ae92d1406c8c46f2b35cffe031ce/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/08e46ece36546bbc2b85ffa90c6a8a4cf3bbab10/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/b293042c81288354130e748246586e2669e423d1/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/6a84f4dc5c9dda9b0a661c34b982f15791783194/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.1/constraint-layout-solver-1.0.1.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.0/ef03cfed144ff47eed2cab1f7be4381bc18a6237/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.0/96a07041a11a09cf578892932d7511e1e11e3b6c/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/79467da2ee5fd2328774a23645475ecb9d0946fd/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/02c10559b235748437a45d6ca44f6c5e5230c4e9/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/82bf4ec6a1051c7130958118c35d8fb99643c133/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/8dd8873d08fda228f6ea3117e6073fd14e35a5d4/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/8fc507ef1c90eab75de9d0123ad4b7535753f320/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/5fb2bef0cb0bba8cf7f981cadcf1cf142a325276/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/0727c2e3f4507058ea7ae52687ced332bf06362f/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/31d4c76434ce8a5ba46bf630f178e855f7516250/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.2.0/support-annotations-25.2.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.3.0/baseLibrary-2.3.0.jar
Destination for generated sources was modified by kapt. Previous value = /home/harisvsulaiman/AndroidStudioProjects/Hafiz/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug
:app:compileDebugKotlinAfterJava
w: The '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-module' is specified
:app:copyDebugKotlinClasses UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebugUnitTest
:app:compileDebugUnitTestKotlin UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestKotlinAfterJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:copyDebugUnitTestKotlinClasses UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugAndroidTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebugAndroidTest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
Processor path was modified by kapt. Previous value = /home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0/jsr305-2.0.1.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-annotations-processor/3.0.0/61c2ac9e7a068736558e69d585cfa777b35058b2/realm-annotations-processor-3.0.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/479c1e06db31c432330183f5cae684163f186146/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/5de0c73fef18917cd85d0ab70bb23818685e4dfd/hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-annotations/3.0.0/32a01bbb8cb421b6d53d7a102412142b0391c8c7/realm-annotations-3.0.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/12537e43a85ab0afa777ffffaa3156b34b448f54/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/67ff45d9ae02e583d0f9b3432a5ebbe05c30c966/javawriter-2.1.1.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/793aa84797fecdb3ba2f8477970a8b447c352cbd/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/ce412e8a194fce2780827ef6800ab6ff4b18323d/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/7e420608fba4187802d4eaa0ca3d7f5c55016f84/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/44be9593d071350b5f9d23c72dca4110a3c5e62a/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/5de0c73fef18917cd85d0ab70bb23818685e4dfd/hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0/jsr305-2.0.1.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/479c1e06db31c432330183f5cae684163f186146/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/478fd1ace0e77af57c87f42a281aed180d5ce276/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/d7d6ec093cb49766f796118979b331d6f5c2b4c4/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-annotations/3.0.0/32a01bbb8cb421b6d53d7a102412142b0391c8c7/realm-annotations-3.0.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/17205aea1b3195cf38fb66c2e060ee4beed141f8/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/adapter-rxjava/2.2.0/d80514b6f44f0c4c6234e2d67fea783a25e77275/adapter-rxjava-2.2.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.2.0/41e67dba73c3347e4503761642c39d0e06ca1f2/retrofit-2.2.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.6.0/69edde9fc4b01c9fd51d25b83428837478c27254/okhttp-3.6.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.11.0/840897fcd7223a8143f1d9b6f69714e7be34fd50/okio-1.11.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.6/de0c509ae6c9db5b5b6004a9d102c92708346f7c/rxjava-1.2.6.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/3.7.0/9e9eeaf9948ee4d6c3ab354e8dc14368f16994a4/glide-3.7.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/6249fbc26c3c324164d6bccd213e772dbffabab8/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/00346f3603afd369923753ca5b3574b3cbd68913/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/44456db0af44370448077b85155ec1b111460aaf/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/ab1b9ebddb2122246c96bfd338f92a2af4329445/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.airbnb.android/epoxy-annotations/1.7.5/509abda14719aa31f55123c9a757bdadc8f45818/epoxy-annotations-1.7.5.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/fb128d6e98efde38d1b59985fb85f2eee1b186eb/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/c9550d2fd003ae92d1406c8c46f2b35cffe031ce/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/08e46ece36546bbc2b85ffa90c6a8a4cf3bbab10/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/b293042c81288354130e748246586e2669e423d1/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/6a84f4dc5c9dda9b0a661c34b982f15791783194/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.1/constraint-layout-solver-1.0.1.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.0/ef03cfed144ff47eed2cab1f7be4381bc18a6237/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.0/96a07041a11a09cf578892932d7511e1e11e3b6c/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/79467da2ee5fd2328774a23645475ecb9d0946fd/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/02c10559b235748437a45d6ca44f6c5e5230c4e9/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/82bf4ec6a1051c7130958118c35d8fb99643c133/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/8dd8873d08fda228f6ea3117e6073fd14e35a5d4/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/8fc507ef1c90eab75de9d0123ad4b7535753f320/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/5fb2bef0cb0bba8cf7f981cadcf1cf142a325276/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/0727c2e3f4507058ea7ae52687ced332bf06362f/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/.android/build-cache/31d4c76434ce8a5ba46bf630f178e855f7516250/output/jars/classes.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.2.0/support-annotations-25.2.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.3.0/baseLibrary-2.3.0.jar:/home/harisvsulaiman/AndroidStudioProjects/Hafiz/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug
Destination for generated sources was modified by kapt. Previous value = /home/harisvsulaiman/AndroidStudioProjects/Hafiz/app/build/generated/source/apt/androidTest/debug
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse data binding compiler options. Params:
  kapt.annotations : /home/harisvsulaiman/AndroidStudioProjects/Hafiz/app/build/tmp/kapt/debugAndroidTest/wrappers/annotations.debugAndroidTest.txt
  kapt.kotlin.generated : /home/harisvsulaiman/AndroidStudioProjects/Hafiz/app/build/tmp/kapt/debugAndroidTest/kotlinGenerated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

`build.gradle` File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.spar.hafiz"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.6'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.10'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:epoxy:1.7.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    kapt 'com.airbnb.android:epoxy-processor:1.7.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had solved same issue.

Delete this code.

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

And add this code.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Reference Links: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/09/kotlin-1-0-4-is-here/